# Canvas子要素のRectangleオブジェクトを回転させた後で、見た目上のRectangleの各頂点座標を取得したい

Tags: c#, wpf

環境/言語：Windows10 Professional, Visual Studio 2019 / WPF, C#

下記の様にCanvas子要素として追加したRectangleを、RotateTransformで角度を指定して回転させています。
この時、Canvas上における、回転後のRectangleの各頂点座標を取得したいのですが、適当な方法が分からず質問させていただきました。
Canvas.GetTopなどのメソッドを使っても、取得できるのは回転していない状態での座標となり、見た目状の頂点座標が
取得できません。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

```
   <Canvas Name="TestCanvas">
            <Rectangle Name="TestRectangle" Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>

    </Canvas>
```

2020.04.30追記：
v..snow様からの回答を元に、目的の座標が取得できるようになりました。
確認用のコードを下記します。

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Testrect.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        Point xRenderTopLeftPt = GetTopLeftVertex(Testrect);
    }

    public Point GetTopLeftVertex(Rectangle dRectangle)
    {
        //Rectangle中心からみた回転前左上座標
        Point RectTopLeftFromRectCenter = new Point(-1 * dRectangle.Width / 2, -1 * dRectangle.Height / 2);
        //Canvas原点からみたRectangle中心座標
        Point RectCenterFromCanvasOrigin = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(dRectangle) + dRectangle.Width / 2, Canvas.GetTop(dRectangle) + dRectangle.Height / 2); 

        var rendertransform = dRectangle.RenderTransform; //対象のRectangleのTransform情報
        var renderlocalTopLeft = rendertransform.Transform(RectTopLeftFromRectCenter); //Rectangle中心からみた回転後左上座標

        //Canvas原点からみた座標に変換
        var renderCanvasTopLeft = renderlocalTopLeft + new Vector(RectCenterFromCanvasOrigin.X, RectCenterFromCanvasOrigin.Y);

        //確認用ﾏｰｶｰ
        Ellipse marker = new Ellipse();
        marker.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
        marker.Width = 10;
        marker.Height = 10;

        Canvas.SetLeft(marker, renderCanvasTopLeft.X - marker.Width / 2);
        Canvas.SetTop(marker, renderCanvasTopLeft.Y - marker.Height / 2);

        TestCanvas.Children.Add(marker);

        return renderCanvasTopLeft;

    }
```

[image: 実行後画像]

Comment: 解決した場合はお礼コメントではなく"承認"するのが推奨されているようです https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers　もしも回答は不十分だったが自己解決したなどという場合は自分で回答として投稿して自己承認することも可能です。

Comment: 回答を承認させていただきました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

トランスフォームの Transform メソッドで座標変換計算を行うことができます。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.generaltransform.transform

例:

```
<Window ... >
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="TestCanvas">
            <Rectangle Name="TestRectangle" Fill="Red" 
                       Width="100" Height="100" 
                       Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" 
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup x:Name="TestTransform">
                        <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Ellipse Name="TopLeftMarker" Fill="Blue" Width="10" Height="10"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowTopLeft();
    }

    void ShowTopLeft()
    {
        // (-50,-50): 長方形中心から見た変換前の左上の座標
        // (150,150): キャンバス原点から見た長方形中心の座標
        var renderlocalTopLeft = TestTransform.Transform(new Point(-50, -50));
        var renderCanvasTopLeft = renderlocalTopLeft + new Vector(150, 150);

        Trace.WriteLine($"{renderCanvasTopLeft.X} {renderCanvasTopLeft.Y}");
        Canvas.SetLeft(TopLeftMarker, renderCanvasTopLeft.X - TopLeftMarker.Width / 2);
        Canvas.SetTop(TopLeftMarker, renderCanvasTopLeft.Y - TopLeftMarker.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: アドバイスいただいたサンプルコードを元に、目的のRectangle回転後座標が取得できました！ありがとうございます。